# Error being thrown within async function gets caught

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, terminate

I want to use an async function instead of returning a promise, however to reject I need to throw an error like this:

```
async function asyncOperation() {
  throw new Error("Terminate this application.");
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await asyncOperation();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
  console.log("Nope, I am still running!"); // This will be printed regardless
})();
```

This means that to catch the reject I must put the function call within a try statement. By doing this, instead of terminating the application, I catch the error and I can continue afterwards.

This of course works as you would expect however I want to throw an error to actually terminate the application regardless if the function was called within a try statement or not.

How could I achieve this without checking the error within the catch statement?

Comment: "*I want to use an async function instead of returning a promise*" makes no sense. All `async function`s return promises.

Comment: You can use the same without the `try` block and it will sort of crash your app every time.

Comment: @Bergi In a matter of fact, that is true however I don't want to literally return promises.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj But the problem is, I might have other errors that I do want to catch.

Comment: As mentioned in an answer below, you can use `process.exit()` if you just want to exit here instead of throwing an error. But a better approach would be to throw a custom error and then in your global error handler you can add a specific condition for that custom error only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to throw an error to actually terminate the application

No. Throwing exceptions is done only to be able to catch and *handle* them. If you really wanted to terminate your application no matter what (which would be a bad, untestable design), you'd just call [`process.exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) and be done with it.

> I might have other errors that I do want to catch.

It sounds like what you actually want is to handle some of the thrown errors but let those that are unhandled terminate the application as usually - unless caught and handled further up in the chain. For that, you'll want to conditionally re-throw the exception:

```
try {
    …
    throw Object.assign(new Error("…"), {reason: X});
    …
} catch (e) {
    if (e.reason == Y) 
        console.error(e);
    else
        throw e;
}
console.log("I won't run after X errors!");
```

Notice that none of this actually has to do with `async`/`await`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Noticed, I removed the tag.